# How to check for an arbitrary condition in a message queue in Spin?

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

I'm trying to simulate the behaviour of other model-checkers using Spin. For that, I need to be able to test for some arbitrary condition in the message queue. For instance, I want to check if somewhere in the channel there exists some message with an int greater than 5. Not only that, I need such condition to be inside an atomic block.

I tried doing something like this:

```
int mid;

do
:: atomic {
  in??[msg(mid)] && mid > 5 -> (...)
}
```

But Spin reads that condition as

```
in??[msg(mid)] && 0 > 5
```

I've tried something of this sort:

```
do
:: atomic {
    in??<msg(mid)>;
    if
    :: mid > 5 ->
        in??msg(eval(mid));
        (...)
    :: else -> skip
    fi }
```

Which works, but is semantically different from what I want because it gets into the atomic block only for it to fail that condition and skip it.

So, is there some way of checking for an arbitrary condition in a message queue and to only execute an atomic block if such condition is valid?

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, the native filtering mechanism offered by `Spin` is only able to *filter by value* and, more specifically, it is unable to *filter by expression*.

This may not look like an ideal solution, but the simplest approach is to evaluate the Boolean expression associated with the filtering condition before the message is sent.

**Example:**

```cpp
chan c = [42] of { int, bool };

proctype Test()
{
    int value;
    do
        :: atomic {
            c??[value, true] ->
                c??value, true; // true: filter messages larger than 5
                printf("Popped: %d\n", value);
            }
        :: else ->
            printf("No more messages larger than 5.\n");
            break;
    od;

    bool cond;
    printf("\nDischarging Channel..\n");
    do
        :: c?[value, cond] ->
           c?value, cond;
           printf("Popped: %d\n", value);
        :: else ->
            break;
    od;
}

init {
    int i;
    for (i : 1 .. 10) {
        c!i(i >= 5)  // evaluate filtering condition when message is sent
    }

    run Test();
}
```

**Output:**

```sh
~$ spin test.pml 
          Popped: 5
          Popped: 6
          Popped: 7
          Popped: 8
          Popped: 9
          Popped: 10
          No more messages larger than 5.

Discharging Channel..
          Popped: 1
          Popped: 2
          Popped: 3
          Popped: 4
2 processes created
```

---

I admit that this is not really a scalable approach, but *I could not come up with any other solution*.